# Magento category export and import with id and path

Tags: category, import, csv, export

Is there a way to export and import categories with paths and ids?
Anyone maybe have already written code?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible in default Magento. I don't know a way to export categories, but there are modules which allow importing categories: **AvS_FastSimpleImport, ApiImport, magmi and uRapidFlow Pro**.

Comment: how to export sku and category path not category name